# Show only the item with the classname equal to the multiple selected checkbox values jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, checkbox

I want to create a filter system where only the articles with a classname equal to the selected checkbox value will show.
The user is able to select multiple cb's and the results should be only those articles.

I know how to show the article with the same selected checkbox value, but when multiple are selected the article that doesn't contain one of those cb value is still shown, so I tried to make it smarter.
So far no luck.

EDIT Link: http://strosslenet.nl/demo/ -- changed the link so others can look as well.

jQuery code:

```
$("#filters :checkbox").click(function() { // if click on a checkbox
    $(".widget-lijst article").hide(); // hide all the items first

    var valCB = $(this).val() // value of the checkbox;

    $("#filters :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
        var valObj = $("." + $(this).val()); // value of the object
        var $allClasses = valObj.attr('class').split(' '); // splits every class in a object

        console.log(valObj);

        for(var i=0; i < $allClasses.length; i++) {

            if($allClasses == valCB) {

                console.log('true');

            } else {

                console.log('false');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

HTML code:

```
<ul id="filters">
  <li>Type
    <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox" value="category-sc" id="sc" /><label for="category-sc">Site content</label></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" value="category-va" id="va" /><label for="category-va">Visitor accelerator</label></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" value="category-ad" id="ad" /><label for="category-ad">Ad only</label></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The items are created by Wordpress posts.
Ajaxshowtime has classe 'category-sc'
Babes Panorama has class 'category-va' 
Beaumonde has both

So ideal situation would be that when both Visitor accelerator and Site content are selected, only Beaumonde would show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like the following (I have added comments in code)

```js
$("#filters :checkbox").change(function() { // if checkbox state changes (in case a label is clicked)
    $(".widget-lijst article").hide(); // hide all the items first

    var selector = ''; // create a selector
  
    $("#filters :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
      selector += '.' + $(this).val();  // append selected values to selector (no spaces so classes are combined if multiple)
    });
  
    $(selector).show(); // show matching articles
});
```

Comment: Wow it seems to be working! I'm going to add more posts and filter options to see if it continues to work. Unfortunately I can do this after a few hours, but I sure will come back and accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:checkbox').click(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        $('.'+value).toggle();
    });
});

.category {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    display: none;
}

<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="article" value="category01"> Category 01
    <input type="checkbox" name="article" value="category02"> Category 02
    <input type="checkbox" name="article" value="category03"> Category 03
    <input type="checkbox" name="article" value="category04"> Category 04
</div>
<div>
    <div class="category category01">
        Article category01
    </div>
    <div class="category category01">
        Article category01
    </div>
    <div class="category category01">
        Article category01
    </div>
    <div class="category category01">
        Article category01
    </div>
    <div class="category category02">
        Article category02
    </div>
    <div class="category category02">
        Article category02
    </div>
    <div class="category category02">
        Article category02
    </div>
    <div class="category category03">
        Article category03
    </div>
    <div class="category category03">
        Article category03
    </div>
    <div class="category category04">
        Article category04
    </div>
</div>
```

This might solve your problem. Please check this.

https://jsfiddle.net/ganesh16889/r359ysdt/

Comment: Hi, unfortunately with my html code, this wouldn't show the articles with the same class name. It would only show one when one is selected while it should show at least two.

Comment: In your script, you have a code to hide all the articles first. I mean this one **$(".widget-lijst article").hide();** . Please avoid that.

Comment: In my example. It shows all the article of selected checkboxes.

Comment: I copied your code and replaced it, but Pete managed to give what I was looking for. Thank you anyway :)